# Using Codeigniter classes

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can I use Codeigniter classes without implementing the whole mvc pattern the same way I can do it with Zend? For example, I would love to be able to use just some validation classes, or email class etc..

Comment: Sure you can, you might possibly have to modify the class a bit so that it is completely detached from CI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course you can, but since some CI classes depend on certain aspects of the CI core (with good reason), you'll probably need to walk through the classes you wish to use to make sure it won't break. This isn't necessarily a terrible thing, as it will let you really understand what you're using. I haven't ever done it myself, but I've heard it's not particularly difficult to do. Give it a try and see how it works.